# Why I do not see the content of the file in my browser?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$content=file("xml.txt");
echo '<pre><code>';
foreach($content as $val){
   echo $val;
 }
echo '</code></pre>';
?>
```

This is the text file i am trying to read through that php code. This code is working fine with text but unfortunately not reading the code.
The code below is the xml.txt file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="softs.hh.androidpermissions.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why are you using a `foreach` for a file?

Comment: Check page source (ctrl+u), just to be sure.

Comment: You still need to escape the content inside a `<pre>` tag - see [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Do you have your own "file" function?

Comment: @AslanShemilov `file()` is a core php function https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Do you mean because they aren't doing anything special with each line?

Comment: @FirstOne exactly; no idea what they want to do here. Probably wants to parse as xml elements, who knows.

Comment: Look at your HTML source; it's there alright [just as @FirstOne said earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326725/my-text-file-contains-code-and-php-unable-to-read-it#comment83638783_48326725).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner because file() returns array. So for reading content from file i am using foreach

Comment: @FirstOne that's android code which i have in xml.txt file. I am reading this file on some webpage.

Comment: @iainn Thanks! That works. You can answer it in post and i'll accept it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap the lines with htmlentities:

```
$content=file("xml.txt");
echo '<pre><code>';
foreach($content as $val){
    echo htmlentities($val);
}
echo '</code></pre>';
```